# Why a database error appears in generated code?

Tags: mysql, database, xampp

I have a project to do for my school on databases. Firstly, I've created the Logical and Relational databases with Oracle(data modeler) and afterwards I generated the code. That code was converted into mySQL via SQLines converter. When I open Xampp and phpmyamdin to run the database an error seems to be occurred.

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE address 
(
    country               CHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    street                CHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    city                  CHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    region                CHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    postal_code           INTEGER NOT NULL,
    customer_customer_id  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    country_fax_code      VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX address__idx ON
    address (
        customer_customer_id
    ASC );

ALTER TABLE address ADD CONSTRAINT address_pk PRIMARY KEY ( country );

CREATE TABLE customer 
(
    customer_id      INTEGER NOT NULL,
    full_name        CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    email            VARCHAR(40),
    address_country  CHAR(40) NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX customer__idx ON
    customer (
        address_country
    ASC );

ALTER TABLE customer ADD CONSTRAINT customer_pk PRIMARY KEY ( customer_id );

CREATE TABLE customer_reservation 
(
    customer_customer_id          INTEGER NOT NULL,
    country_fax_code              VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    reservations_reservation_id   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    reservations_flight_id1       INTEGER NOT NULL,
    reservations_reservation_id1  INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE fax 
(
    country_fax_code      VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    region_fax_code       INTEGER NOT NULL,
    local_number          INTEGER NOT NULL,
    customer_customer_id  INTEGER,
    country_fax_code1     VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE fax ADD CONSTRAINT fax_pk PRIMARY KEY ( country_fax_code );

CREATE TABLE flight 
(
    flight_id           INTEGER NOT NULL,
    airline_id          INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    businessclass       DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    smokerseats         DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    flight_status_id1   DOUBLE NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX flight__idx ON
    flight (
        flight_status_id1
    ASC );

ALTER TABLE flight ADD CONSTRAINT flight_pk PRIMARY KEY ( flight_id );

CREATE TABLE flight_status 
(
    flight_id             INTEGER NOT NULL,
    date_departure        DATETIME NOT NULL,
    time_departure        DATETIME NOT NULL,
    flight_time           INTEGER NOT NULL,
    total_businessclass   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    reserved_business     INTEGER NOT NULL,
    total_economy         INTEGER NOT NULL,
    reserved_economy      INTEGER NOT NULL,
    flight_flight_id      INTEGER NOT NULL,
    reservation_id        INTEGER NOT NULL,
    flight_status_id      DOUBLE NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX flight_status__idx ON
    flight_status (
        flight_flight_id
    ASC );

ALTER TABLE flight_status ADD CONSTRAINT flight_status_pk PRIMARY KEY ( flight_status_id );

CREATE TABLE flight_taxes 
(
    airport                       CHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    local_currency                CHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    exchange_rate                 DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    total_taxes                   DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    reservations_reservation_id   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    reservations_flight_id1       INTEGER NOT NULL,
    reservations_reservation_id1  INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX flight_taxes__idx ON
    flight_taxes (
        reservations_reservation_id
    ASC,
        reservations_flight_id1
    ASC,
        reservations_reservation_id1
    ASC );

CREATE TABLE phone 
(
    country_phone_code    VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    region_phone_code     INTEGER NOT NULL,
    local_number          INTEGER NOT NULL,
    customer_customer_id  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    country_fax_code      VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL 
);

ALTER TABLE phone ADD CONSTRAINT phone_pk PRIMARY KEY ( country_phone_code );

CREATE TABLE reservations 
(
    reservation_id       INTEGER NOT NULL,
    date_of_reservation  DATETIME NOT NULL,
    flight_id            INTEGER NOT NULL,
    datetime_departure   DATETIME(6) NOT NULL,
    datetime_arrival     DATETIME(6) NOT NULL,
    seat_type            CHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    total_price          DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    flight_cost          DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    reservation_status   CHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    payment_in_advance   DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    rest_of_payment      DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    flight_flight_id     INTEGER NOT NULL,
    reservation_id1      INTEGER NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE reservations
    ADD CONSTRAINT reservations_pk PRIMARY KEY ( reservation_id,
                                                 flight_flight_id,
                                                 reservation_id1 );

ALTER TABLE address
    ADD CONSTRAINT address_customer_fk FOREIGN KEY ( customer_customer_id )
        REFERENCES customer ( customer_id );

ALTER TABLE customer
    ADD CONSTRAINT customer_address_fk FOREIGN KEY ( address_country )
        REFERENCES address ( country );


ALTER TABLE customer_reservation
    ADD CONSTRAINT customer_reservation_fk FOREIGN KEY ( customer_customer_id )
        REFERENCES customer ( customer_id );

ALTER TABLE customer_reservation
    ADD CONSTRAINT customer_reservation_fk1 FOREIGN KEY ( reservations_reservation_id,
                                                                      reservations_flight_id1,
                                                                      reservations_reservation_id1 )
        REFERENCES reservations ( reservation_id,
                                  flight_flight_id,
                                  reservation_id1 );

ALTER TABLE fax
    ADD CONSTRAINT fax_customer_fk FOREIGN KEY ( customer_customer_id )
        REFERENCES customer ( customer_id );

ALTER TABLE flight
    ADD CONSTRAINT flight_flight_status_fk FOREIGN KEY ( flight_status_id1 )
        REFERENCES flight_status ( flight_status_id );

ALTER TABLE flight_status
    ADD CONSTRAINT flight_status_flight_fk FOREIGN KEY ( flight_flight_id )
        REFERENCES flight ( flight_id );

ALTER TABLE flight_taxes
    ADD CONSTRAINT flight_taxes_reservations_fk FOREIGN KEY ( reservations_reservation_id,
                                                              reservations_flight_id1,
                                                              reservations_reservation_id1 )
        REFERENCES reservations ( reservation_id,
                                  flight_flight_id,
                                  reservation_id1 );

ALTER TABLE phone
    ADD CONSTRAINT phone_customer_fk FOREIGN KEY ( customer_customer_id )
        REFERENCES customer ( customer_id );

ALTER TABLE reservations
    ADD CONSTRAINT reservations_flight_fk FOREIGN KEY ( flight_flight_id )
        REFERENCES flight ( flight_id );



CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER flight_status_id1 BEFORE
    INSERT ON flight_status
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN new.flight_status_id IS NULL THEN
BEGIN
             Set new.flight_status_id = flight_status_id1.nextval;
END;
/
```

Error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHEN new.flight_status_id IS NULL THEN
BEGIN
                Set new.flight_status_id =' at line 4
```

Unfortunately I can't figure out where the problem is and how to fix that as a newbie. Any help?

Comment: The trigger has not converted to mysql syntax.

Comment: There in NO `NEXTVAL` in MySQL.

Comment: The main problem is that we haven't learned to write code in mySQL. They want us to create an Logical and Relational model,generate it and then convert it into mySQL.

Comment: Everything apart from the trigger seems fine and I don't see how a trigger could be part of a logical and/or relational model.

Comment: @P.Salmon I've deleted the trigger part as you told me. Everything seems to working fine . Thanks

Comment: `auto_increment` for `flight_status.flight_id` would be sufficient.